SQL Unique Constraint Across Multiple Database Tables
So a variation of this question has been asked many times; in all of those cases, usually the recommendation is a modifying of the data and the suggested rewrites often make more sense but I can't figure out a way, with my specific example.
Basically, all elements are of a shared type. So there's a single, shared table; say, Animals with the columns animal_id, animal_name, animal_type, number_of_legs, etc. You get the idea.
The data is coming in from elsewhere so, while there's a few types we can expect, that's not the case all over.
So we might have a Mammals table and a Reptiles table. Receive a type of animal which I haven't accounted for? No worries; the animal_type column (which is a varchar) will capture that info. If I decide I want to account for that type of animal in a designated way or it has data that the other animals don't, I can extend my database and add a table for it. Mammals would have a mammal_id primary key which is a foreign key to animal_id; same deal with Reptiles and reptile_id, etc.
And each table can have further subtypes; so animal_types of Dogs, Cats, etc. could end up in Mammals and I can tell the difference based on the animal_type listed in Animals.
So say Mammals has a field like owner or something; but owner is dependent on the animal_type. So people can't own more than one Cat but can own a Cat and a Dog.
If animal_type were in Mammals, this would be trivial: unique constraint on animal_type and owner. But animal_type applies to every Animal so it wouldn't make sense in only that table. I could put animal_type in both Animals and Mammals but this is duplicating and replicating data in multiple tables with no assurance of syncing.
I may just not be knowledgeable enough in SQL, yet, but what's the best way to enforce that no owner has an Animal of more than one of one animal_type?
EDIT: this isn't an inheritance question; inheritance is already established. This is a question of how to handle a particular column's data and their relationship when relevant to multiple tables in a Class Table Inheritance context. The linked-to supposed duplicate question does not, at any point, address when a particular column applies to all inherited "classes" (like animal_type does to all Animals) while that data is also relevant to a particular parent "class" (in this case, Mammals).
It may be there's no easy or available solution to this problem but it's not remotely addressed in the proposed duplicate.

Don't have separate tables for Mammals, Reptiles, etc. Have a single table for all animals and include the Mammal/Reptile/whatever data in a column in that table. You can include a second categorisation table for Dogs/Cats/Crocodiles too, if you need that level of detail

You can use separate relationship tables. Person_owns with columns owner_id, animal_type, animal_id. Add a unique constraint on (owner_id, animal_type)

Simple answer is: use a computed column (or a column with a CHECK for only one value) for the type column in the child tables, and have the child tables in a 1:1 relationship, where the PK and FK are the same column. So you have Mammal (Id int PK, Type varchar, UNIQUE (Id, Type)) and then Animal (Id int PK, Type varchar CHECK (Type = 'Animal'), FK (Id, Type) REFERENCES Mammal (Id, Type))

@Barmar: the only issue with this is not every animal is owned (just Mammals) but every Animal has a type. So, like I mentioned in my original question, Person_Owns would end up duplicating the info. of the animal_type column since it has to be in the Animals table.

@tangentially-perpendicular: That could, obviously, work but there's a variety of subtype of animals so that table's going to get big, fast.

You can't have cross-table constraints, so if you want uniqueness in ownership, you need to duplicate it in the ownership table. Or implement this in application logic rather than the DB.

@Barmar: Yeah…I figured that'd be the case. But mostly wanted to double check, just in case I was missing anything or missing a recommended best practice. Thanks!

@Jaft - "table getting big fast" -- That's not a problem.  Multiple tables -- That's a mess.
